# Systemctl: find out which commands are applicable for a service

Tags: centos7, systemd, systemctl

How do I find out which commands are applicable for a service with systemctl?

```
# systemctl reload nagios.service
failed to reload nagios.service: Job type reload is not applicable for unit nagios.service.
```

With init.d you could run the script without command and see the usage info for applicable commands:

```
# /etc/init.d/nagios 
Usage: /etc/init.d/nagios {start|stop|status|restart|condrestart|try-restart|reload|force-reload|configtest}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`systemctl` is not like the good old init-scripts. According to its `man` page and its [source code](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/main/src/systemctl/systemctl-start-unit.c), it supports the following commands that are like the init-script commands you are searching for:

- `start`  Start (activate) one or more units specified on the command line.
- `stop` Stop (deactivate) one or more units specified on the command line.
- `reload` Asks all units listed on the command line to reload their configuration.
- `restart` Stop and then start one or more units specified on the command line. If the units are not running yet, they will be started.
- `try-restart` Stop and then start one or more units specified on the command line if the units are running. This does nothing if units are not running.
- `reload-or-restart` Reload one or more units if they support it. If not, stop and then start them instead. If the units are not running yet, they will be started.
- `try-reload-or-restart` Reload one or more units if they support it. If not, stop and then start them instead. This does nothing if the units are not running.

The following redundant aliases exist, mostly for legacy reasons:

| Verb | Aliases |
| --- | --- |
| `try-reload-or-restart` | `reload-or-try-restart`, `condreload`, `force-reload` |
| `try-restart` | `condrestart` |
| `stop` | `condstop` |

So the group of these commands comes down to `start`, `stop` and `reload`. Since `start` and `stop` are necessary for most service types (and you normally know if a service does not support one of them), the only thing you could want to know about is if a given service supports `reload` or not.

Most times, you want it to either reload or restart: use `systemctl reload-or-restart nagios` then. To really find out what command (if any) is executed for reloading, you can look into its service file. This can usually be found in `/lib/systemd/system/` or `/usr/lib/systemd/system` and is named `$SERVICENAME.service` (in your case `nagios.service`). This file contains commands for starting, stopping and maybe reloading the service, namely `ExecStart`, `ExecStop` and `ExecReload`. If you're interested in that, you could do a `grep ExecReload /lib/systemd/system/nagios.service` to find out if a service supports reloading or not.

As @LucaRicci pointed out, more elaborate services can have a `ReloadSignal` instead of the `ExecReload`, which they will answer to via [sd_notify](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sd_notify.3.html) to indicate success.

**TL;DR**

`systemctl` essentially supports `start`, `stop` and `reload`. To find out if a Service supports reloading, just try it. If you need to reload multiple services in a script or something, use `reload-or-restart`, which reloads the service if it has an `ExecReload`-command or `ReloadSignal` stored, otherwise it restarts it.

Comment: Thank you! "reload-or-restart" is really useful to know.

Comment: @Mitja could you enhance your already great answer by confirming that `reload` on a stopped service won't start it; and what about `reload-or-restart` on a stopped service?

Comment: @4wk_ you probably want `try-reload-or-restart PATTERN...` According to manpage: "          Reload one or more units if they support it. If not, stop and then start them instead. This does nothing if the units are not running."

Comment: What about `Type=notify-reload` services? They don't have *ExecReload* but send *ReloadSignal* (or SIGHUP) to the main process...

Comment: @LucaRicci If I understand [the man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sd_notify.3.html) correctly, such a service must call `sd_notify()` with `RELOADING=1` to signal that it processes the reload command. I added that to the answer, thanks.